# Mod-rewrite not working on Network Solutions server

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a website that requires mod-rewrite to function well, but it seems to not be functional on the Network Solutions shared server we're running on.  Network Solutions promises it's installed but won't provide any further support without additional payment.

I placed a simple test at the following folder which contains two files. The first, ".htaccess" contains the following text:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^link([^/]*).html$ rewrite.php?link=$1 [L]
```

The second is the PHP script which tests it, available here:
http://www.oceanhousefloridakeys.com/testmr/rewrite.php

All I see is that mod-rewrite is installed (no error messages showing) but the rewriteRule is not working.  Can anybody see why this script isn't working... is there anything I can do to get it running, or is Network Solutions not telling the whole truth?

Comment: Is mod_rewrite *enabled*? Do you have access to the command line? I believe you use `a2enmod rewrite` to enable it. Also, do you know if you have `AllowOverride` set to `All` for that directory in your Apache configuration?

Comment: @Travesty3: "Is mod_rewrite enabled?" This is the big question... Network Solutions swears that it's enabled, but since this simple test above doesn't work, I don't fully believe them. Unfortunately, I do not have access to the command line since I'm on a shared server, so I can't give you more feedback.

Comment: Have you tried it with a leading slash in the regex? Like `^/link([^/]*).html$`? When it's in a sub-folder: have you set `RewriteBase` accordingly?

Comment: @vstm: Yes! Adding RewriteBase solved the issue. Please post this as the answer to this question. FYI...adding the leading slash did not help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like your script resides inside a sub-directory. In that case it's the best solution to set the [`RewriteBase`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase) to the correct path (before any `RewriteRule`):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /testmr/
RewriteRule ^link([^/]*).html$ rewrite.php?link=$1 [L]
```