# Hiding Extensions with .htaccess not working with Network Solutions

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am working with a client who uses Network Solutions for hosting.  I have created their website so that all of the .php extensions are hidden in the url using the .htaccess file.  Everything is working fine on my server, but when I transfer it to Network Solutions, the links do not work.  They give me a vague answer that their servers have trouble with this and it will not work unless I use the extensions.  Is there a way around this or another simpler method that might work?

Here are two methods I have tried that work everywhere I have tried, but Net Sol:

Options +MultiViews

and

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

Comment: What exactly does "not working" mean? Are you getting errors? What does your error logs say? Are you getting incorrect content?

Comment: This is what I am getting: 404: Page not found This error is generated when there was no web page with the name you specified at the web site.

Comment: Are you sure your htaccess file is being read?

Comment: I used a test that I found here: http://www.qualitytuts.com/check-htaccess-is-working-or-not-on-server/ and it was successful with a new .htaccess file so I know  mod_rewrite is working.

Answer (score 2):

Previously I also faced problem with removing .html or .php extension form URL.

I have a Solution Here

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

put the above code in .htaccess file, above code is for .php files.

Hope it helps You.. :)

Comment: Nearly four years later, and this effectively fixes my problem. Kudos to you!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution here: [Mod-rewrite not working on Network Solutions server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10934952/mod-rewrite-not-working-on-network-solutions-server).  Needed to add RewriteBase /directory/ because I had my files in a sub-directory.